# How do I format the document?

Tags: formatting, positioning

I have a document. This is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,enumerate,tabularx,calrsfs,esvect, multicol}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=20mm,top=15mm,bottom=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[thmmarks,standard,thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
%\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{pro}{Problem}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{pro}
Solve  the following equations:
\begin{enumerate}[\quad 1)]
\item $\dfrac{\cos^2 2x}{\cos x + \cos\dfrac{\pi}{4}} = \cos x - \cos\dfrac{\pi}{4}$;
\item $\dfrac{\cos^2 2x}{\cos x + \cos\dfrac{\pi}{4}} = \cos x - \cos\dfrac{\pi}{4}$;

\item $(\sqrt{3}\sin x + 2\cos x)\cdot (1 - \cos x) = \sin^2 x$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{pro}


\begin{pro}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (4.3,4.5);
\draw (0,0)-- (4,0);
\draw (4,0)-- (2,3.46);
\draw (2,3.46)-- (0,0);
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.03,-0.19) node {$B$};
\fill [color=black] (4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (4.1,-0.19) node {$C$};
\fill [color=black] (2,3.46) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.99,3.72) node {$A$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.615\textwidth}
Write the equation of the plane which passes the point and perpendicular to the line $\Delta$ 
\end{minipage}
\end{pro}
\end{document}
```

I want to Problem 2 above, the equilateral triangles on the left and content of  the  problem on the right. Moreover, the total widths of the two minipapes equal to  width of the page. How do I do that? Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please trim your question to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I tried, but I can not.

Comment: @minthao_2011 Have a look at the resources Matthew linked you to! Without a proper MWE, your question will most likely be closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one possibility; I used `t` for the optional argument for the `minipage`s (to get top vertical alignment) and `baseline=(current bounding box.north)` for the `tikzpicture`. I also removed a spurious blank space after the first `\end{minipage}` so that now the width for both `minipage`s can add up to `\linewidth`. Also I used `font=\scriptsize` for the nodes of the diagram. Depending on the desired position for the label "Problem " one can obtain different alternatives; the following code shows two possibilities:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,enumerate,tabularx,calrsfs,esvect, multicol}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=20mm,top=15mm,bottom=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[thmmarks,standard,thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
%\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{pro}{Problem}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{pro}
Solve  the following equations:
\begin{enumerate}[\quad 1)]
\item $\dfrac{\cos^2 2x}{\cos x + \cos\dfrac{\pi}{4}} = \cos x - \cos\dfrac{\pi}{4}$;
\item $\dfrac{\cos^2 2x}{\cos x + \cos\dfrac{\pi}{4}} = \cos x - \cos\dfrac{\pi}{4}$;

\item $(\sqrt{3}\sin x + 2\cos x)\cdot (1 - \cos x) = \sin^2 x$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{pro}


\begin{pro}\mbox{}\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,baseline=(current bounding box.north),every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]
\clip(-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (4.3,4.5);
\draw (0,0)-- (4,0);
\draw (4,0)-- (2,3.46);
\draw (2,3.46)-- (0,0);
\fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.03,-0.19) node {$B$};
\fill [color=black] (4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (4.1,-0.19) node {$C$};
\fill [color=black] (2,3.46) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.99,3.72) node {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
Write the equation of the plane which passes the point and perpendicular to the line $\Delta$ 
\end{minipage}
\end{pro}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,baseline=(current bounding box.north),every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]
\clip(-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (4.3,4.5);
\draw (0,0)-- (4,0);
\draw (4,0)-- (2,3.46);
\draw (2,3.46)-- (0,0);
\fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.03,-0.19) node {$B$};
\fill [color=black] (4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (4.1,-0.19) node {$C$};
\fill [color=black] (2,3.46) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.99,3.72) node {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
\begin{pro}
Write the equation of the plane which passes the point and perpendicular to the line $\Delta$ 
\end{pro}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a personal note, perhaps you could reconsider the change for `\baselinestretch`?

Another request has been made in a comment: the problem to the left, the figure to the right:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,enumerate,tabularx,calrsfs,esvect, multicol}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=20mm,top=15mm,bottom=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[thmmarks,standard,thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
%\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{pro}{Problem}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
\begin{pro}
Write the equation of the plane which passes the point and perpendicular to the line $\Delta$ 
\end{pro}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,baseline=(current bounding box.north),every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]
\clip(-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (4.3,4.5);
\draw (0,0)-- (4,0);
\draw (4,0)-- (2,3.46);
\draw (2,3.46)-- (0,0);
\fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.03,-0.19) node {$B$};
\fill [color=black] (4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (4.1,-0.19) node {$C$};
\fill [color=black] (2,3.46) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.99,3.72) node {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd move the whole `pro` environment inside the second `minipage`, adding `\noindent` in front of the first one. But that depends on where "Problem 2" is desired. Probably the best is to have the figure on the right.

Comment: @egreg yes, that's another option; I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: How can I put the the figure on the right and the content of problem on the left? Please help me.

Comment: @minthao_2011 please see my updated answer.